# How to change MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: google-sheets

I have imported a CSV file to the spreadsheet that includes columns with Dates and timestamp (Columns D,E,K,L) and I'm currently facing 2 problems with these columns.

1. Some rows are formatted as text/string and I can't seem to change it to date format. I tried manually changing it via format>number>datetime but it remains the same.
2. the format of the date is being read incorrectly by spreadsheet. For example,  5/11/2018 is being read as May 11, 2019 but if you try to review the spreadsheet, it should be read as November 5, 2018. I tried playing with the format and spreadsheet settings to no avail.

[Spreadsheet Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qZq0cv0ux1_Z6KyoihRWorSuQoaH-5eGWwLIAqFEmZg/edit?usp=sharing)

I'd appreciate any inputs.

**UPDATE**

1. For Column D & E, I have already converted all rows to Date but the problem persists where in some rows are being read as DD/MM/YYYY and some rows MM/DD/YYYY. This creates date discrepancy when I try to make data visualization using these data:(
2. I am unable to convert all rows in Column L to date format. Some rows are still being read as text/string.

Comment: It looks like it's File, Spreadsheet Settings, General, Locale: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515

Comment: your sheet is private

Comment: I am in the UK where dd/mm/yyyy is the locale specific date format and your spreadsheet displays correctly without changes.  mm/dd/yyyy is conventional in the US.  The dates were correct despite the locale for the sheet being set to US.  Some of the cells are not date formatted, but are text formatted - the ones that are left rather then right justified.  Not however a programming question, so off-topic on SO unless you are attempting to do this programatically, but that is not clear from your question.

Comment: Hi Clifford, may I know how you were able to change those text formatted data to Date format?

Answer (score 2):

if you have a spare column you can use this formula to correct it:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1; 4); MID(A1; 4; 2); LEFT(A1; 2))
```

also, you can try to change locale settings in your spreadsheet because it looks like that your spreadsheet uses `mm/dd/yyyy` format as default. eg. you can try for example Czech locale where default is `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Is there a way to use this in column K and L?

Comment: sure. change all A1 to K1 or L1

Answer (score 0):

To format custom dates in Google Sheets:

1. Highlight the column to be formatted.
2. Navigate the app's menu path:
   Format >> Number >> More Formats >> More data and time formats
3. Put your cursor in the top field of the popup and edit as necessary...

   - Delete parts you don't want.
   - Add parts you do want (but make sure you're adding them left-to-right).
   - Put character(s) between the fields as separators.
   - Format each part via its dropdown list of options.
4. Click the "Apply" button, and you're done.

[image: google sheets custom date formatting]